# Xml comments in Enterprise architect

Tags: c++-cli, uml, enterprise-architect

all!
I have c++/cli project. I've imported it in Enterprise Architect 8.0. But I've in code xml comments. How can I make EA to show them in class diagrams?

Comment: What makes you think that EA supports this?

Comment: Actually, I don't know if EA support this.
Supports EA displaying any comments for c++/cli code?

Comment: @Oded: it supports it for C#. That makes it worth a try for C++. OTOH, I don't know that version 8 supports C++/CLI at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like EA version 9 supports both C++/CLI and XML documentation comments:

[image]

Comment: The 8 version although supports this. Thank!